# How to send a jchararray as parameter to C function

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, jniwrapper

I am trying to use a C library (Pre-written and published) in an android app. I started my effort about writing a JNI wrapper around this C library. I can't figure out how to pass in `jchararray` properly to C.

```
int getData(char data[], const int dataLen, int unit[], const int unitLen) {
...
}
```

My JNI wrapper looks like

```
Java_eg_test_freqProcessor(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jcharArray data_,
    jintArray unit_) {

    jchar *data = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, data_, NULL);
    jsize dataLen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, data_);
    jint *unit = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, unit_, NULL);
    jsize unitLen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, unit_);

    getData(data, dataLen, unit, unitLen);

    (*env)->ReleaseCharArrayElements(env, data_, data, 0);
    (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, unit_, unit, 0);
}
```

I have verified that `int[]` are passing through to C library well by printing them inside `getData()` method. But the problem is with passing `jcharArray data_` to `char data[]`

I have printed out the `data_` after getting the length using `(*env)->GetArrayLength(env, data_);`. When I print inside `Java_eg_test_freqProcessor` method, I see

```
06-29 23:05:42.364 12278 12348 V EEG    : {
06-29 23:05:42.364 12278 12348 V EEG    : "
06-29 23:05:42.364 12278 12348 V EEG    : 0
06-29 23:05:42.364 12278 12348 V EEG    : "
06-29 23:05:42.364 12278 12348 V EEG    : :
06-29 23:05:42.364 12278 12348 V EEG    :  
06-29 23:05:42.364 12278 12348 V EEG    : 1
06-29 23:05:42.364 12278 12348 V EEG    : }
```

But inside the `getData()` method, if I iterate on the same set I only see half of the data.

```
06-29 23:08:07.801 12573 12651 V EEG Inside: 0 : {:
06-29 23:08:07.802 12573 12651 V EEG Inside: 1 :
06-29 23:08:07.802 12573 12651 V EEG Inside: 2 : ":
06-29 23:08:07.802 12573 12651 V EEG Inside: 3 :
06-29 23:08:07.802 12573 12651 V EEG Inside: 4 : 0:
06-29 23:08:07.802 12573 12651 V EEG Inside: 5 :
06-29 23:08:07.802 12573 12651 V EEG Inside: 6 : ":
06-29 23:08:07.802 12573 12651 V EEG Inside: 7 :
```

This library performs in place transformation of `data[]` which I need to access later. I understand that `jchar` is a byte larger than `char` but I still can't understand the correct way of approaching this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`jchar` is not `char` but rather `uint16_t` (or `unsigned short`). Java strings seem to have UTF-16 encoding.

Take a look at the accepted answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320235/how-to-convert-java-strings-to-wide-character-strings-using-jni)